# Is it Possible to save particular files anywhere in salesforce?

Tags: lightning-web-components, fileupload

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="LWC File Upload Example" icon-name="custom:custom19">
    <lightning-file-upload
        label="Attach CSV file"
        name="fileUploader"
        accept={acceptedFormats}
        record-id={recordId}
        onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
        multiple>
</lightning-file-upload>
</lightning-card>
```

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class FileUploadLWC extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
get acceptedFormats() {
    return ['.csv'];
}
handleUploadFinished(event) {
    // Get the list of uploaded files
    const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
    let uploadedFileNames = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
        uploadedFileNames += uploadedFiles[i].name + ', ';
    }
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: uploadedFiles.length + ' Files uploaded Successfully: ' + uploadedFileNames,
            variant: 'success',
        }),
    );
}
```

}

The above code I am using as Tab. I need to show files only uploaded through this. Basically, I need to upload a file, and should show below the upload button. Whenever we open this it should load all files uploaded through this functionality.

Is it possible in Salesforce LWC?

Appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using this component on any specific record page? If yes, store all file Ids in a Textarea field and retrieve the file Ids on component load, and use Navigation service to preview the file. Sample code for file preview can be found here - https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/09/file-preview-in-lwc.html

Comment: No, I am using this as Tab. Sorry I mentioned wrong. I am using this file upload as Tab